# Disable JSF page for few seconds on commandButton click

Tags: jsf, commandbutton

I need to disable all components of a jsf page on button click and show a countdown to , say 10 sec, before the page automatically  refreshes.

Please share your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use any 3party component library.
Use [Primeface BlockUI](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/blockUI.jsf), which can be helpful in blocking UI components.